# Does a read only BehaviorSubject interface exist in RX and if not, is it a bad idea to make one?

Tags: swift, system.reactive, rx-swift

Implementations of rx provide `BehaviorSubject<T>` and `Variable<T>` as mechanisms for modeling properties that change over time (a useful replacement for C# INotifyPropertyChanged).

Generally these are exposed as `Observable<T>` but it would be more useful to expose properties as something like:

```
class ObservableValue<T> : Observable<T>{
  var currentValue:T { get }
}
```

This can be created along these lines in swift:

```
class ObservableValue<Element> : ObservableType {

  typealias E = Element

  private let subject:BehaviorSubject<E>

  var currentValue:E {
      get {
          return try! subject.value()
      }
  }

  init(subject:BehaviorSubject<E>) {
      self.subject = subject
  }

  func subscribe<O: ObserverType where O.E == E>(observer: O) -> Disposable {
      return self.subject.subscribe(observer)
  }
```

}

Does this already exist? and if not is it because it's against the aims of Rx?

The only way around it is to expose a separate currentValue or write consumers that assume the concrete implementation behind the exposed Observable is a BehaviourSubject or somewhere in the chain a replay() has occured e.g. the following snippet doesn't make it explicit that as soon as I subscribe I will get a value:

```
class MyViewModel {
  // 'I will notify you of changes perhaps including my current value'
  myProperty:Observable<String> 
}
```

so code has to be written as if its 'asynchronous' with an underlying assumption it will act in an almost synchronous manner rather than:

```
class MyViewModel {
  // 'I have a current value and will notify you of changes going forward'
  myProperty:ObservableValue<String> 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having thought it over and discussed it a bit more presumably the reason it doesn't (and perhaps shouldn't exist) is that it's an introduction of imperatively accessed state.

Other mechanisms of maintaining state (such as `scan`) do so within the confines of chained observables rather than as 'dead-end' direct calls such as 'give me the value right now'.

Perhaps it would have it's place in a hybrid reactive/imperative approach but it may just hinder full embracement of the reactive style.

It's analogous to using promises or tasks in half of the code then reverting to synchronous blocking code in other parts.

Comment: It exsists in RxCocoa as a Driver, for UI this si rather nice

Answer (score 0):

In most cases what people do is create a standard view model that exposes properties via INotifyPropertyChanged. This allows UI elements to bind to them and receive property change events and keep the UI in sync.

Then if you want an IObservable for said property you take advantage of standard Rx operators that turn events into IObservable. You can google this to find lots of different implementations. You would generally create and consume these observables from something that is observing the view model rather than expose them on the view model directly.

Comment: That would work in Rx.NET because you have INotifyPropertyChanged but in swift you don't (closest is KVO which is only on NSObject subclasses).  Also I'm not sure I like the idea of exposing a get/set, an INotifyPropertyChanged and an Observable somewhere - if I'm making the viewmodel why haven't I just made it straight with observables rather than mix event systems.